# Magento Category description not showing as it should

Tags: php, magento

When I enter a description for a magento category, it displayes the content right after the title:

[image]

The "test test" is the description. I want the description to appear underneath the title. Here is my code for rendering the code (/template/catalog/category::view.phtml):

```
<div class="page-title category-title title-r title-visible">
    <?php if($this->IsRssCatalogEnable() && $this->IsTopCategory()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getRssLink() ?>" class="link-rss"><?php echo $this->__('Subscribe to RSS Feed') ?></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <h1><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name'); ?></h1>
    <?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <span class="category-description std"> <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

This is the code that is outputted:

```
<div class="page-title title-rewite">
    <h1>
        Bisquertt Family Vineyards
         test test
    </h1>
</div>
```

Why does this happen, when the `<h1>` tag is closed, before rendering the description?

Comment: are you sure there is no cache? seems like the div class has issues updating too.

Comment: All caches are cleared

Comment: And if you add more span elements they will be outputed inside <h1> too? then just delete the tag and reinsert it, there may be a bug somewhere. I run your code on my end and it displays properly. also validate your code from source code, maybe there are unclosed tags before, in the header..

Comment: check whether h1 tags has given some css